# What are sealed classes in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm a beginner in Kotlin and recently read about [Sealed Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html). But from the doc the only think I actually get is that they are exist.

The doc stated, that they are "representing restricted class hierarchies". Besides that I found a statement that they are enums with superpower. Both aspects are actually not clear.

So can you help me with the following questions:

- What are sealed classes and what is the idiomatic way of using ones?
- Does such a concept present in other languages like Python, Groovy or C#?

**UPDATE:**
I carefully checked this [blog post](https://kotlinexpertise.com/kotlin-sealed-class-restricted-class-hierarchy/) and still can't wrap my head around that concept. As stated in the post

> **Benefit**
>
> The feature allows us to define class hierarchies that are
> restricted in their types, i.e. subclasses. Since all subclasses need
> to be defined inside the file of the sealed class, there’s no chance
> of unknown subclasses which the compiler doesn’t know about.

Why the compiler doesn't know about other subclasses defined in other files? Even IDE knows that. Just press `Ctrl+Alt+B` in IDEA on, for instance, `List<>` definition and all implementations will be shown even in other source files. If a subclass can be defined in some third-party framework, which not used in the application, why should we care about that?

Comment: The documentation seems reasonably clear: "A sealed class can have subclasses, but all of them must be declared in the same file as the sealed class itself." It's a restriction in terms of what subclasses are possible.

Comment: Also, as the docs show, since nobody else can create new subclasses of the sealed class, a `when` expression can guarantee that all possible subclasses are handled.

Comment: @DaisyShipton what if I declare all subclasses in the same file but without `sealed` modifier?

Comment: Then that wouldn't prevent *other* subclasses being created in other files, which may well not be what you want - it would violate the expectation in zsmb13's comment, for example.

Comment: After reading a few more posts over the Internet, I see only one reasoning of `sealed` class. It's compilation performance. With `sealed` modifier the compiler already knows that no more subclasses exist, while without it the compiler can process `when` expressions only after all source files are handled, i.e. as a second step

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Say you have a domain (your pets) where you know there is a definite enumeration (count) of types. For example, you have two and only two pets (which you will model with a class called `MyPet`). Meowsi is your cat and Fido is your dog.

Compare the following two implementations of that contrived example:

```
sealed class MyPet
class Meowsi : MyPet()
class Fido : MyPet()
```

Because you have used sealed classes, when you need to perform an action depending on the type of pet, then the possibilities of `MyPet` are exhausted in two and you can ascertain that the `MyPet` instance will be exactly one of the two options:

```
fun feed(myPet: MyPet): String {
    return when(myPet) {
       is Meowsi -> "Giving cat food to Meowsi!"
       is Fido -> "Giving dog biscuit to Fido!" 
    }
}
```

If you don't use sealed classes, the possibilities are not exhausted in two and you need to include an `else` statement:

```
open class MyPet
class Meowsi : MyPet()
class Fido : MyPet()

fun feed(myPet: MyPet): String {
    return when(myPet) {
       is Mewosi -> "Giving cat food to Meowsi!"
       is Fido -> "Giving dog biscuit to Fido!" 
       else -> "Giving food to someone else!" //else statement required or compiler error here
    }
}
```

In other words, without sealed classes there is not exhaustion (complete coverage) of possibility.

Note that you could achieve exhaustion of possiblity with Java `enum` however these are not fully-fledged classes. For example, `enum` cannot be subclasses of another class, only implement an interface (thanks [EpicPandaForce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce)).

What is the use case for complete exhaustion of possibilities? To give an analogy, imagine you are on a tight budget and your feed is very precious and you want to ensure you don't end up feeding extra pets that are not part of your household.

Without the `sealed` class, someone else in your home/application could define a new `MyPet`:

```
class TweetiePie : MyPet() //a bird
```

And this unwanted pet would be fed by your `feed` method as it is included in the `else` statement:

```
       else -> "Giving food to someone else!" //feeds any other subclass of MyPet including TweetiePie!
```

Likewise, in your program exhaustion of possibility is desirable because it reduces the number of states your application can be in and reduces the possibility of bugs occurring where you have a possible state where behaviour is poorly defined.

Hence the need for `sealed` classes.

Comment: this answer is finally sort things out in my head about sealed classes

Comment: I tried your example, and am not getting in to the scenario ->  `else statement required or compiler error here`, why ?

Comment: I somehow do not agree with your answer a sealed class still can be extended right? if so then let's take class TweetiePie: MyPet() I would still need to cover for classes under TweetiePie right?

Answer (score 11):

Sealed classes are easier to understand when you understand the kinds of problems they aim to solve. First I'll explain the problems, then I'll introduce the class hierarchies and the restricted class hierarchies step by step.

We'll take a simple example of an online delivery service where we use three possible states `Preparing`, `Dispatched` and `Delivered` to display the current status of an online order.

---

### Problems

**Tagged class**

Here we use a single class for all the states. Enums are used as type markers. They are used for tagging the states `Preparing`, `Dispatched` and `Delivered` :

```
class DeliveryStatus(
    val type: Type,
    val trackingId: String? = null,
    val receiversName: String? = null) {
    enum class Type { PREPARING, DISPATCHED, DELIVERED }
}
```

The following function checks the state of the currently passed object with the help of enums and displays the respective status:

```
fun displayStatus(state: DeliveryStatus) = when (state.type) {
    PREPARING -> print("Preparing for dispatch")
    DISPATCHED -> print("Dispatched. Tracking ID: ${state.trackingId ?: "unavailable"}")
    DELIVERED -> print("Delivered. Receiver's name: ${state.receiversName ?: "unavailable"}")
}
```

As you can see, we are able to display the different states properly. We also get to use exhaustive `when` expression, thanks to enums. But there are various problems with this pattern:

**Multiple responsibilities**

The class `DeliveryStatus` has multiple responsibilities of representing different states. So it can grow bigger, if we add more functions and properties for different states.

**More properties than needed**

An object has more properties than it actually needs in a particular state. For example, in the function above, we don't need any property for representing the `Preparing` state. The `trackingId` property is used only for the `Dispatched` state and the `receiversName` property is concerned only with the `Delivered` state. The same is true for functions. I haven't shown functions associated with states to keep the example small.

**No guarantee of consistency**

Since these unused properties can be set from unrelated states, it's hard to guarantee the consistency of a particular state. For example, one can set the `receiversName` property on the `Preparing` state. In that case, the `Preparing` will be an illegal state, because we can't have a receiver's name for the shipment that hasn't been delivered yet.

**Need to handle `null` values**

Since not all properties are used for all states, we have to keep the properties nullable. This means we also need to check for the nullability. In the `displayStatus()` function we check the nullability using the `?:`(elvis) operator and show `unavailable`, if that property is `null`. This complicates our code and reduces readability. Also, due to the possibility of a nullable value, the guarantee for consistency is reduced further, because the `null` value of `receiversName` in `Delivered` is an illegal state.

---

### Introducing Class Hierarchies

**Unrestricted class hierarchy: `abstract class`**

Instead of managing all the states in a single class, we separate the states in different classes. We create a class hierarchy from an `abstract class` so that we can use polymorphism in our `displayStatus()` function:

```
abstract class DeliveryStatus
object Preparing : DeliveryStatus()
class Dispatched(val trackingId: String) : DeliveryStatus()
class Delivered(val receiversName: String) : DeliveryStatus()
```

The `trackingId` is now only associated with the `Dispatched` state and `receiversName` is only associated with the `Delivered` state. This solves the problems of multiple responsibilities, unused properties, lack of state consistency and null values.

Our `displayStatus()` function now looks like the following:

```
fun displayStatus(state: DeliveryStatus) = when (state) {
    is Preparing -> print("Preparing for dispatch")
    is Dispatched -> print("Dispatched. Tracking ID: ${state.trackingId}")
    is Delivered -> print("Delivered. Received by ${state.receiversName}")
    else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unexpected state passed to the function.")
}
```

Since we got rid of `null` values, we can be sure that our properties will always have some values. So now we don't need to check for `null` values using the `?:`(elvis) operator. This improves code readability.

So we solved all the problems mentioned in the tagged class section by introducing a class hierarchy. But the unrestricted class hierarchies have the following shortcomings:

**Unrestricted Polymorphism**

By unrestricted polymorphism I mean that our function `displayStatus()` can be passed a value of unlimited number of subclasses of the `DeliveryStatus`. This means we have to take care of the unexpected states in `displayStatus()`. For this, we throw an exception.

**Need for the `else` branch**

Due to unrestricted polymorphism, we need an `else` branch to decide what to do when an unexpected state is passed. If we use some default state instead of throwing an exception and then forget to take care of any newly added subclass, then that default state will be displayed instead of the state of the newly created subclass.

**No exhaustive `when` expression**

Since the subclasses of an `abstract class` can exist in different packages and compilation units, the compiler doesn't know all the possible subclasses of the `abstract class`. So it won't flag an error at compile time, if we forget to take care of any newly created subclasses in the `when` expression. In that case, only throwing an exception can help us. Unfortunately, we'll know about the newly created state only after the program crashes at runtime.

---

### Sealed Classes to the Rescue

**Restricted class hierarchy: `sealed class`**

Using the `sealed` modifier on a `class` does two things:

1. It makes that class an `abstract class`. Since Kotlin 1.5, you can use a `sealed interface` too.
2. It makes it impossible to extend that class outside of that file. Since Kotlin 1.5 the same file restriction has been removed. Now the class can be extended in other files too but they need to be in the same compilation unit and in the same package as the `sealed` type.

```
sealed class DeliveryStatus
object Preparing : DeliveryStatus()
class Dispatched(val trackingId: String) : DeliveryStatus()
class Delivered(val receiversName: String) : DeliveryStatus()
```

Our `displayStatus()` function now looks cleaner:

```
fun displayStatus(state: DeliveryStatus) = when (state) {
    is Preparing -> print("Preparing for Dispatch")
    is Dispatched -> print("Dispatched. Tracking ID: ${state.trackingId}")
    is Delivered -> print("Delivered. Received by ${state.receiversName}")
}
```

Sealed classes offer the following advantages:

**Restricted Polymorphism**

By passing an object of a `sealed class` to a function, you are also sealing that function, in a sense. For example, now our `displayStatus()` function is sealed to the limited forms of the `state` object, that is, it will either take `Preparing`, `Dispatched` or `Delivered`. Earlier it was able to take any subclass of `DeliveryStatus`. The `sealed` modifier has put a limit on polymorphism. As a result, we don't need to throw an exception from the `displayStatus()` function.

**No need for the `else` branch**

Due to restricted polymorphism, we don't need to worry about other possible subclasses of `DeliveryStatus` and throw an exception when our function receives an unexpected type. As a result, we don't need an `else` branch in the `when` expression.

**Exhaustive `when` expression**

Just like all the possible values of an `enum class` are contained inside the *same class*, all the possible subtypes of a `sealed class` are contained inside the *same package and the same compilation unit*. So, the compiler knows all the possible subclasses of this `sealed` class. This helps the compiler to make sure that we have covered(exhausted) all the possible subtypes in the `when` expression. And when we add a new subclass and forget to cover it in the `when` expression, it flags an error at compile time.

Note that in the latest Kotlin versions, your `when` is exhaustive for the `when` *expressions* as well the `when` *statements*.

**Why in the same file?**

The same file restriction has been removed since Kotlin 1.5. Now you can define the subclasses of the `sealed class` in different files but the files need to be in the same package and the same compilation unit. Before 1.5, the reason that all the subclasses of a `sealed class` needed to be in the same file was that it had to be compiled together with all of its subclasses for it to have a closed set of types. If the subclasses were allowed in other files, the build tools like Gradle would have to keep track of the relations of files and this would affect the performance of incremental compilation.

**IDE feature: `Add remaining branches`**

When you just type `when (status) { }` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the IDE automatically generates all the possible branches for you like the following:

```
when (state) {
    is Preparing -> TODO()
    is Dispatched -> TODO()
    is Delivered -> TODO()
}
```

In our small example there are just three branches but in a real project you could have hundreds of branches. So you save the effort of manually looking up which subclasses you have defined in different files and writing them in the `when` expression one by one in another file. Just use this IDE feature. Only the `sealed` modifier enables this.

---

That's it! Hope this helps you understand the essence of sealed classes.

Answer (score 8):

If you've ever used an `enum` with an `abstract method` just so that you could do something like this:

```
public enum ResultTypes implements ResultServiceHolder {
    RESULT_TYPE_ONE {
        @Override
        public ResultOneService getService() {
            return serviceInitializer.getResultOneService();
        }
    },
    RESULT_TYPE_TWO {
        @Override
        public ResultTwoService getService() {
            return serviceInitializer.getResultTwoService();
        }
    },
    RESULT_TYPE_THREE {
        @Override
        public ResultThreeService getService() {
            return serviceInitializer.getResultThreeService();
        }
    };
```

When in reality what you wanted is this:

```
val service = when(resultType) {
    RESULT_TYPE_ONE -> resultOneService,
    RESULT_TYPE_TWO -> resultTwoService,
    RESULT_TYPE_THREE -> resultThreeService
}
```

And you only made it an enum abstract method to receive compile time guarantee that you always handle this assignment in case a new enum type is added; then you'll love sealed classes because sealed classes used in assignments like that `when` statement receive a "when should be exhaustive" compilation error which forces you to handle all cases instead of accidentally only some of them.

So now you *cannot* end up with something like:

```
switch(...) {
   case ...:
       ...
   default:
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type: " + enum.name());
}
```

---

Also, enums cannot extend classes, only interfaces; while sealed classes can inherit fields from a base class. You can also create multiple instances of them (and you can technically use `object` if you need the subclass of the sealed class to be a singleton).

Answer (score 0):

They're basically enums except that since they're classes they can have arbitrary properties and functions.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to give a pictorial explanation,

The sealed class is like a container.
The compiler creates a container of all classes that derive from the sealed class.

Now the compiler recognizes all the derived classes of the sealed class and can make comparisons like in the "when" expression.